# Como realizar una peticion AJAX a php?(Con JavaScript Vanilla)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, ecmascript-6

Estoy intentando hacer una peticion AJAX a un metodo en mi controlador Marcas.

```
const filter = () => {
let data = {marca:"a"};
fetch("www.algoalgo.com/marcas/marcas/filtro",{
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data) ,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(response=>{
    return response.json();
}).then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
});
}
```

Aqui esta el controlador:

```
   public function filtro(){

    $marca = $_POST["marca"];
     //Aqui esta la llamada a el modelo,que busca en la base marcas que contengan "a".
    $data = $this->Productos->filtro($marca); 

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Pero en consola me aparece el siguiente error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined index: marca

Como puedo hacer para que se ejecute correctamente?

Comment: Prueba con `body: data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta dónde puedo ver el error está en el Content-Type, esto puede sonar un poco ostentoso, pero en el verdadero javascript vanilla, se usa es XMLHttpRequest, fetch es un wrapper con promesas (o una nueva api que no tiene nada que ver con XMLHttpRequest, todavía no leo al respecto). Con XMLHttpRequest el modo de enviar los datos, el Content-Type, es

```
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

que es el tipo de contenido que envían cómo tal los formularios básicos en html, y desde javascript se utilizaba el FormData para enviar los datos, que es cómo todavía lo hago, aunque me solicitaron probar con la nueva api.

Si utiliza ese tipo de contenido, es muy probable, que la petición sea reconocida por el servidor cómo variables para llenar la superglobal $_POST.

Por otro lado, con

```
"Content-type": "application-json"
```

Supongo que el modo de procesar esos datos es extrayendo la cadena "cruda" (raw), y procesándola con json_decode en php.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Lo cual va a tomar la información del flujo de entrada directa de php, que generalmente es una cadena de texto y usando la función o el método correspondiente se puede convertir ese texto en formato json, al tipo de dato correspondiente que se pueda procesar desde el lenguaje de turno.

Comment: En la facu me enseñaron como que fetch es lo ahora "recomendado" por ES6...
Pero voy a probar hacerlo con XMLHttpRequest.
La idea era hacerlo en vanilla pero lo solucione con Jquery!
Gracias!

Comment: No, síquelo haciendo con fetch, sólo decía que ese era el modo vanilla, pero es mejor usar las últimas apis. La verdad es que con XMLHttpRequest es más complejo. En cambio si cambias sólo el tipo de dato que envias desde fetch, o el cómo lo recuperas en php, es más fácil.  Exitos!